# Processing, signal-processing and text-processing tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Could we rename Processing (the language) tag to Processing-lang, and merge signal- and text-processing tags to data-processing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does data-processing mean?

Although it's clear what [processing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/processing) refers to -- and I agree with renaming that tag to clarify that it's about the *processing language* itself; tag [signal-processing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing) and tag [text-processing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) don't have any usage guidance. I'm leery of combining two already ill-defined groups of questions into another even less-well-defined group.

I took a look at the existing tagged questions, there's currently 25 questions tagged [signal-processing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing?sort=votes&pagesize=50) and 9 questions tagged [text-processing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing?sort=votes&pageSize=15).

I can guess that [signal-processing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing) would include digital signal processing techniques (within the Arduino's capability), as well as analog filtering.

Browsing the 9 questions tagged [text-processing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing?sort=votes&pageSize=15), it's not clear to me what this tag actually means.

- how an Arduino program(sketch) deals with strings of text input and output?
- how the C pre-processor processes the text of the source code?
- how the Arduino-specific language elements work?

Is [program-got-so-many-errors-about-expected-or-before-either](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/program-got-so-many-errors-about-expected-or-before-either) really about text processing? Seems like this question turned out to be about why `#define dw 8;` should not have the semicolon.  Similarly [arduino-program-got-error-expected-primary-expression-before-token-error](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8470/arduino-program-got-error-expected-primary-expression-before-token-error) doesn't contain anything that looks to me like text processing.

What about this question about [F() FlashStringHelper](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17774/any-way-to-use-f-macro-with-a-passed-variable) -- that's useful and related to how constant string expressions are stored in an arduino program, but probably belongs in [string](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) instead.

And for that matter, why *isn't* [How do I split an incoming string](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-do-i-split-an-incoming-string) in text-processing when [How to get string parts from string](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/10557/how-to-get-string-parts-from-string) is? I'd edit it myself if I was sure what belonged in that tag.

So since [text-processing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) has only 9 questions, and 0 followers, and it's unclear how these questions are related, let's instead:

1. rename [processing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/processing) to processing-lang as proposed by @Avamander
2. shore up [signal-processing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing) with a clear tag wiki definition
3. dispatch the 9 questions in [text-processing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) to wherever they really belong (maybe [string](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)), then burninate [text-processing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing).
4. add [text] as a synonym for [string](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Re-tagging individual questions is a straightforward edit, but without a clear well-defined definition of what the tag is supposed to mean, it's harder to find related stuff.

Comment: Done. (Although signal-processing still needs a description)